# Parsear un string a cualquier tipo de dato en C++

Tags: c++

Tengo una clase llamada `Token` la cual tiene un atributo llamado `valor` que almacena el valor del token y un atributo `tipo` que indica de que tipo es. Esta clase lo que hace más que nada es clasificar una cadena que ya ha sido analizada sintácticamente. Por ejemplo, la cadena `"hola"` es clasificada como `STRING` y el valor almacenado es `hola`.

Mi problema ocurre al momento de comparar Tokens, pues para cualquier tipo de compaación necesitaría castear o convertir el string almacenado al tipo de dato correspondiente. Se me ocurrió usar el modulo `any` para esto pero tendría que tener una serie de `if` para hacer la validación correspondiente de cada token.

Mi clase es así:

```cpp
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Token {
private:
    string valor;
    int tipo, num_linea;
public:
    Token() = default;
    Token(bool tk, int linea): valor(string(tk ? "verdadero": "falso")), num_linea(linea){}
    Token(string tk, int linea){
        valor = tk;
        if (tk == "=") tipo = ASIGNACION;
        else if (tk == ";") tipo = END;
        else if (tk[0] ==  '"' && tk[tk.size() - 1] == '"') {
            tipo = STRING;
            valor = tk.substr(1, tk.size() - 2);
        }
        else if (tk.size() == 1 &&  Operadores.find(tk)) tipo = OPERADOR;
        else if (tk == "NADA") tipo = NADA;
        else if (tk == "verdadero" || tk == "falso") tipo = BOOL;
        else if (esEntero(tk)) tipo = ENTERO;
        else if (!isdigit(tk[0]) && validIdentificador(tk)) tipo = IDENTIFICADOR;
        else throw TokenError(linea);
        num_linea = linea;
    }
    int getTipo() { return tipo; }
    string getValor() { return valor; }
    int getLinea() { return num_linea; }
    
    Token operator ==(Token& tk) {
        if(tk.getTipo() != tipo ) return Token(false, num_linea);

        // no se como castear al tipo correspondiente
        auto val = any_cast<int>(tk.getValor());
        return Token(tk.getValor() == valor, num_linea);
    };

    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Token& tk){
        os << tk.valor;
        return os;
    }
};
```

**Los tipos de datos son constantes y están definidas en otro archivo, un ejemplo sería** `#define ENTERO 1`

Como ven en la sobrecarga del operador `==` uso `any_cast` para transformar el string a entero, pero para hacerlo totalmente funcional y que detecte los demás tipos debería usar una serie de `if` para validar cada token (el que se recibe por parámetro y el actual que sería `this`). Una pequeña implementación sería:

```cpp
Token operator ==(Token& tk) {
    if(tk.getTipo() != tipo ) return Token(false, num_linea);

    if(tipo == ENTERO) return Token(any_cast<int>(tk.getValor()) == any_cast<int>(valor), num_linea);
    if(tipo == STRING) return Token(tk.getValor() == valor, num_linea);
    if(tipo == BOOL) return Token(tk.getValor() == valor, num_linea);
}
```

Y tendría que hacer esto en todas las sobrecargas de operadores que tenga o donde sea que necesite hacer la conversión. Mi idea es tener otro método para esto y que me devuelva el dato ya casteado, pero no logro hacerlo. Intenté creando una función y especificando su tipo de dato de retorno como `any`, lo cual no me funcionó tanto, pues devuelve un dato per igualmente necesito saber el tipo para hacer el casteo.

Lo que hice fue algo como esto:

```
...
private:
    any parse(){
        if(tipo == STRING) return string(valor);
        else if (tipo == ENTERO) return atoi(valor.c_str());
    }
...
```

Pero como mencioné mi problema vendría al hacer `any_cast` del resultado, pues necesito nuevamente conocer el tipo de dato.
¿Cómo podría implementar un método que me devuelva el valor ya convertido?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Has intentado con `strignstream`? Tal vez sea una forma fácil de lograrlo. Encontré [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594520/what-exactly-does-stringstream-do) pregunta del sitio en inglés que tal vez pueda servirte.

Comment: creo que tendré el mismo problema, pues con es puedo convertir el string a lo que yo quiera, pero ¿Cómo lo retorno? ¿Cómo hago una función y que esta me acepte cualquier tipo dato como retorno? Si en algo me equivoco me lo puedes hacer saber y si tienes un código podrías elaborar una respuesta. Gracias :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás la forma más común de resolver este problema es recurriendo al uso de plantillas y sobrecarga.

Algunas razones para justificar este planteamiento podrían ser

- Obtienes directamente el tipo de dato que necesitas
- Las plantillas son una opción bastante versátil y, si está bien implementada, también extensible
- Permiten aislar cada conversión, con sus características, dependencias, ...

Piensa lo complicada que quedaría esta función si tuvieses que implementar conversiones para enteros (con signo y sin signo y con diferente tamaño en bytes), números en coma flotante, booleano y ... ¿tipos personalizados?

Con plantillas y sobrecarga, en cambio, obtienes un mecanismo flexible y extensible a partes iguales.

Así, por ejemplo, podrías definir la función `parse` tal que:

```
template<class T>
T parse() const {
    return token_parser<T>(valor);
}
```

Lo que hace esta función es, simplemente, delegar la conversión en un elemento invocable llamado `token_parser`, que también es una plantilla.

Este elemento es el que se va a encargar de realizar toda la magia.

En principio `token_parser` va a ser una función, luego lo primero que vamos a hacer es declararla:

```
template<class T>
T token_parser(std::string const& valor);
```

A continuación, vas a ir implementando todas las conversiones que necesites:

```
template<>
int token_parser<int>(std::string const& valor)
{
    return std::stoi(valor);
}

template<>
string token_parser<std::string>(std::string const& valor)
{
    return valor;
}

template<>
bool token_parser<bool>(std::string const& valor)
{
    return valor != "0";
}

// ...
```

Si intentas realizar una conversión que no esté implementada, la compilación simplemente fallará

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pDV1BAqwhBUwB7o3)

Comment: No es exactamente lo que quería, pero me reduce bastante el trabajo. Quería tener algo como `auto resultado = parse<token.tipo>(valor)`, pero creo que no es posible. Tu respuesta me ayudó mucho y ya sé como implementarlo. Gracias.

Comment: Una cosa, si quisiera usar la función para la misma clase (osea hacer referencia a la clase desde dentro), me bastaría con hacer `this->parse<int>()`?

Comment: @Christian las plantillas solo pueden usarse con valores definidos en tiempo de compilación.  Las variables se determinan en tiempo de ejecución, lamento confirmarte que no puedes hacer eso

Comment: Lo de `this->parse<int>()`, en cambio, es código totalmente válido